# Dynamically generate a function of varying arity with pattern matching in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Somewhat [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883375/dynamically-generating-a-function-with-pattern-matching-in-ocaml) for Ocaml, I want to dynamically generate functions in Elixir with different arity that can be used to pattern match against varying input.

For instance, if I get an infinite input of list items at run-time, e.g.,

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
# ... etc ...
```

I want to generate functions on a module defined like this:

```
defmodule Example do
  def func([x, y, z]), do: [x, y, z]
  def func([x, y, x]), do: [x, y, x]
  def func ([a, b, c, d]), do: [a, b, c, d]
end
```

Is this possible and if so, how? I know you could do this with macros if the input were defined at compile time, but since the input occurs in real-time at run-time, it seems macros won't work.

Answer (score 3):

It’s possible with a bit of metaprogramming, and the help of [`Macro.generate_arguments/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#generate_arguments/2), [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote/1), and [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote_splicing/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#unquote_splicing/1).

```rb
defmodule Dyn do
  @expected_input [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
  ] |> Enum.map(&length/1) |> Enum.uniq()

  for arity <- @expected_input do
    args = Macro.generate_arguments(arity, __MODULE__)
    def func(unquote(args)), do: unquote(args)
    def func(unquote_splicing(args)), do: unquote(args)
  end
end
```

which works as shown below:

```rb
iex|1 ▶ Dyn.func 1, 2, 3
[1, 2, 3]
iex|2 ▶ Dyn.func [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
iex|3 ▶ Dyn.func [1, 2]    
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Dyn.func/1
```

Note, that the code above generates clauses for both argument as an array, as well as for multiple arguments.